# Why crash when derive from QListWidgetItem AND QObject

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, signals-slots, pyqt5

The following minimal example crashes in pyqt 5.7.1 on windows (copy-paste this in a .py file and run):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListWidgetItem, QListWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal


class MyListItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, 'example')
        obj.sig_name_changed.connect(self.__on_list_item_name_changed)

    def __on_list_item_name_changed(self, new_name: str):
        self.setText(new_name)


class MyListItem2(QListWidgetItem, QObject):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, 'example')
        QObject.__init__(self)
        obj.sig_name_changed.connect(self.pyqt_slot)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def __on_list_item_name_changed(self, new_name: str):
        self.setText(new_name)


class Data(QObject):
    sig_name_changed = pyqtSignal(str)


class SearchPanel(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QListWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        obj = Data()
        hit_item = MyListItem(obj)  # OK
        hit_item = MyListItem2(obj)  # crashes
        self.addItem(hit_item)
        obj.sig_name_changed.emit('new_example')


app = QApplication([])
search = SearchPanel()
search.show()
app.exec()
```

Now just comment out the line that says "crashes", and it works fine. Moreover, the list widget shows 'new_example', showing that the signal went through.

Is there a way to make it work with MyListItem2? i.e. I want to be able to decorate the slot with pyqtSlot, which in turn requires (in PyQt 5.7) that I derive item from QObject.

The intent here is that each item in the list has several characteristics that can change (icon, font, text color) based on signals from associated Data instance (each instance actually "lives", in the Qt sense of the term, in a second thread of our application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with `pyqtSlot`.

The actual problem is that you are trying to inherit from two Qt classes, and that is [not generally supported](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance). The only exceptions to this are Qt classes that implement interfaces, and Qt classes that share a common base-class (e.g. `QListWidget` and `QWidget`). However, only the former is *offically* supported, and there are several provisos regarding the latter (none of which are relevant here).

So a Python class that inherits from both `QListWidgetItem` and `QObject` just will not work. The main problem occurs when PyQt tries to access attributes that are not defined by the top-level base-class (even when the attribute does not exist). In earlier PyQt versions, this would simply raise an error:

```
>>> class MyListItem2(QListWidgetItem, QObject): pass
...
>>> x = MyListItem2()
>>> x.objectName()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: could not convert 'MyListItem2' to 'QObject'
>>> x.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: could not convert 'MyListItem2' to 'QObject'
```

which makes it clear that (in C++ terms) a `MyListItem2(QListWidgetItem)` cannot be cast to a `QObject`. Unfortunately, it seems that more recent versions of PyQt5 no longer raise this error, and instead just immediately dump core (which presumably is a bug).

If you really need to use `pyqtSlot`, one suggestion would be to use composition rather than subclassing. So perhaps something like this:

```
class ListItemProxy(QObject):
    def __init__(self, item, obj):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._item = item
        obj.sig_name_changed.connect(self.__on_list_item_name_changed)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def __on_list_item_name_changed(self, new_name: str):
        self._item.setText(new_name)

class MyListItem2(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, 'example')
        self._proxy = ListItemProxy(self, obj)
```

Comment: You're right, I had read the multi inheritance note but somehow understood the limitation was only for Qt classes derived from QObject (which qlistwidgetitem does not).

Comment: The aggregation approach will work but is not much better than using setData() on the widget item (which is what we ended up doing in pyqt 5.5; but that no longer works in 5.7, see my other post from today) since it too creates a circular reference. I think I will do away with pyqtSlot on this particular component and take the mem/perf hit.

Comment: @Schollii. Out of curiosity, have you ever actually measured the mem/perf cost? I know the pyqt docs make this claim, but I have never seen any hard evidence for it.

Comment: I hadn't but had been wondering, so your question was a good excuse to investigate. I have posted my findings [at code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1123088/PyQt-signal-slot-connection-performance), if you have time to have a look that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Schollii. Thanks for this contribution: it's very impressive! I have no reason to doubt any of your methods or results, which are all pretty much what I expected. For 98% of applications, it seems the gains from using `pyqtSlot` will be swamped by other factors. Indeed, in the example code for this question, it looks like the up-front cost of creating all those extra `QObject` instances would significantly reduce the advantages of using `pyqtSlot`. (Of course, there may be other valid reasons for using `pyqtSlot` which have nothing to do with mem/perf considerations).

Comment: That's a great point: if the choice is between a raw slot without QObject base, and a pyqtSlot with (therefore) QObject base class, AND there are many such objects instantiated... I've extended the article and script for this case (btw articles can be upvoted too ;)